# Name undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a div and in its onclick function I am calling `function Remove()` to which I am passing its id and name. But when I use `name` in my remove function, an `undefined error` is thrown. For example, I call `Remove(1,xyz)` and then in the `Remove` function I am unable to access `xyz`; it's showing me `xyz` is not defined.

Here is my jQuery code which calls the `Remove` function:

```
$("#h2-"+id).append("<div id = 'c2-"+id+"' onclick = 'Remove("+id+","+name+")' class='clear_btn1'>&nbsp;</div>");
```

and here is my `Remove` function:

```
function Remove(i, name){

    alert("I am deleting " +name);

    var sender = "<?php echo $user_check?>";
    var receiver = name;

    console.log("Name is " +sender);
    console.log("receiver is " +receiver);
}
```

The value of `i` is coming perfectly fine but I cannot access `name` in my function.

Comment: can you provide jsFiddle please?

Comment: go to page source and try to understand what value exact render in `onclick='Remove('','')'` and you can use **Inspect Element** in Chrome

Comment: well, your `div` doesn't have a `name` does it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change your code as below**

```
$("#h2-"+id).append("<div id = 'c2-"+id+"' onclick = \"Remove("+id+",'"+name+"')\" class='clear_btn1'>sdfsdf sdfsdf</div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

What is saved in `onclick` is actually `Remove(id,name)`. This looks okay at first look, but...

Say `id=10` and `name="Mark"`.

You would be calling `Remove(10,Mark)`, which is not what you want. `Mark` would be treated as a variable. You therefore need to put additional quotes enclosing name to treat it as a string.

You should, of course, escape the additional quotes you would add.

You need to call `Remove(10,"Mark")`. Notice the quotes.

Comment: Yes by inspecting element i was getting remove fucntion as Remove(1,Mark) not Remove(1,"Mark"). That was the I was unable to access name in my function. Prog provided me the solution.